# How to package tensorflow-gpu model to run on most of the machines?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

Tensorflow GPU version, nvidia driver version, cudnn version has special compatibility matrix. This compatibility matrix creates problem in packaging and ditributing tensorflow model which can run by others without any hassle when I pass them.Container based technologies(e.g. docker) would also have problem as it won't know nvidia driver version. I am wondering if anyone knows the best way to package tensorflow model which can automatically configure according to underlying nvidia driver on the linux system. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use a base docker image with tensorflow-gpu installed and  then create your own docker file over it. Something like "FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3"  and then your requirements in the dockerfile.

Comment: @AkashBasudevan Usually docker becomes machine specific. If the machine has some specific nvidia driver, only certain cuda version (9.x or 10.x) with cudnn works. Also, sometimes tensoflow-gpu has to be donwgraded. I have tried transferring perfectly running docker on one machine to another. On another machine, I had to several changes in docker to make it work. My problem is that when I pass this to production team, they would expect it work smoothly. How can I know nvidia driver information automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use tensorflow image with docker
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/
and for GPU you can use the nvidia tools with preinstalled existing image or add it up with the  docker file..

Comment: The above link mentions:
-gpu tags are based on Nvidia CUDA. You need nvidia-docker to run them. NOTE: GPU versions of TensorFlow 1.13 and above (this includes the latest- tags) require an NVidia driver that supports CUDA 10. See NVidia's support matrix.